# How to search for a puzzle?

Tags: support

I have a puzzle I would like to post, which makes me think of three things:

1) How do I search to see if it has been posted before? Details change in retellings, and so many individual words are common, making a search challenging.

2) If there are types of questions, are there examples to aid is appropriate tagging and searching? Types would have to be many, not few, as broad categories do not help searching.

3) Am I allowed to ask for "more like this"? If questions on puzzling are to garner answers, would "more like this" be a question here (on meta)?

Comment: Adding a short summary of the question you're trying to ask will allow us to give you more specific advice. General advice like this can frequently be too broad to be helpful to you.

Comment: I *am* asking a general question. It is *because* of this puzzle that i was wondering *in general*. If, however, you are saying that each puzzle i might search for is best asked here first, i will have the answer to my question and then post it too. :)

Comment: thinking of a river crossing question: does it really matter if it's a wolf and a goat and a cabbage? it could be as well a fox, a rabbit and a carrot - and if they don't cross a river maybe they cross a lake...   so i totally agree with please delete me when it's hard to find a question!!!